# Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging in React App firebase9

Tags: reactjs, firebase

// I am working on Login/Register from in React and I am using firebase auth for
authentication. When the user logged in I want to redirect the user on the root path or
on App component. But I got into an infinite loop which gives me this error (#Throttling
navigation to prevent the browser from hanging.#)//

```
                                 **App Js**

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { getUserAuth } from "./actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <>
                <Header />
                <Home />
              </>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getUserAuth: () => dispatch(getUserAuth()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

                             //App Section End//

                                 **LogIn**

import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signInAPI } from "../actions";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {props.user && <Navigate to="/home" />}
      <Nav>
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/images/login-logo.svg" alt="" />
        </a>
        <div>
          <Join>Join now</Join>
          <SignIn>Sign in</SignIn>
        </div>
      </Nav>
      <Section>
        <Hero>
          <h1>Welcome to your professional community</h1>
          <img src="/images/login-hero.svg" alt="" />
        </Hero>
        <Form>
          <Google onClick={() => props.signIn()}>
            <img src="/images/google.svg" alt="" />
            Sign in with Google
          </Google>
        </Form>
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.userState.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  signIn: () => dispatch(signInAPI()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);


                       //LogIn Section End to identify the error //

                            **SignIn**

import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { signInWithPopup, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { SET_USER } from "./actionType";

export const setUser = (payload) => ({
  type: SET_USER,
  user: payload,
});

export function signInAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((payload) => {
        // console.log(payload.user);
        dispatch(setUser(payload.user));
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
}

export function getUserAuth() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setUser(user));
      }
    });
  };
}

export function signOutAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(setUser(null));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
}
                      **End SignIn**

//**Throttling navigation** to prevent the browser from hanging.//
//Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls 
  setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or 
  one of the dependencies changes on every render. Unable to identify the error //
```

Comment: Add a dependency to your `useEffect`.

Comment: can you solve the problem? I have already used dependency but did not getting the result. if you can kindly do the same.